# How to make the DropDownList selected value persist after a POST action in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use this DropDownList stuff for the first time, and so far, I didn't achieve my goal. My goal is to have a DDList, and after the desired value is selected, we use the `onchange` event to do the post action, but after the POST action is done, the DDList resets to the first value, making impossible to select the first item.

Guys, I know there are better ways around it (like not using this onchange, or instead of a DDList using a ul or a table, but I'm trying to understand POST actions and DDList, in case I have to use this again.

Can you gentle guys help me out?

Answer (score 1):

when loading data to the DD, you must validate first

```
if (!isPostBack)
    fillDD();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm in MVC4.  In case anybody else has trouble understanding here is my solution to the problem.

```
//Razor View
     @Html.DropDownList("StateID", (SelectList)ViewBag.stateList, "--Select--")

 //Code
    public ActionResult Create()
      {
         MyOtherData d = new MyOtherData();
         //Load the Dropdown here
         ViewBag.stateList = new SelectList(db.State, "StateID", "Name");
         return View(d);
      }


  [HttpPost]
//Notice the 2nd parameter StateID in Action Result must match the 4th parameter in the ViewBag SelectList Below and the first parameter in the DropDownList called StateID.
//The 4th parameter will act like the SelectedItem we were all familiar with in ASP.Net

    public ActionResult Create(ModelData data, String StateID)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          //...  
        }
       //Return SelectList to the dropdownlist here
        ViewBag.stateList = new SelectList(db.State, "StateID", "Name", StateID);

        return View(data);
    }
```